# Launch process (file) within from a .jar script

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to figure out how I could for example run a file/app which is located on my desktop. 
In this case, to test everything, I created a batch file called *test.bat* and inside there is the command:

```
@echo
msg * hello
```

Which will pop-up a message box.

This should be launched within Netbeans with a jButton, so this is what I currently have:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            // TODO add your handling code here:

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec("msg * hello");


    }
```

However every time I hit that button, nothing happens.

In addition, I read several posts here on stackoverflow, but still cant figure out what I'm doing wrong, since I get an error message by adding those lines
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("start test.bat");

for this line:

```
Process pr = rt.exec("start test.bat");
```

Which says:

> unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be
>   thrown

How can I launch (maybe otherwise) the test.bat file by pushing the button?

And I have read other posts but none of them are talking about this IOExceptions.

AGAIN! there is now solution yet, which i have found for this error, so stop marking this post as a duplication....

This is what i got with the try catch, its working now.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process pr = rt.exec("msg * hello");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exec will work with 'start' as start is not a process. You'll want to do something like, "cmd /k start test.bat"

Comment: Or maybe like that, but the real problem here is that i dont get my script to work, due that caught and thrown declaration....

Comment: thanks chrisw69 for the comment, helped too!

Answer (score 0):

This is now the working code:

```
String programFilesx86= System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)");

 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {

            Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /k start \"\" \""+programFilesx86+"\\Folder\\test.exe\" " );
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```